# Method invocation style subprogram call in the Ada Reference Manual

Tags: methods, ada

I understand that there is a method invocation style subprogram call in Ada, however, I can’t find anything on it in the Reference Manual.

Could someone please point me to the corresponding section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "method invocation style subprogram call" I assume you mean the "object.method(parameters)" invocation style.

This is not addressed in the Subprogram invocation section, where one might've thought, but instead is in [4.1.3, Selected Components](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-1-3.html), paragraphs 9.1/2 and 9.2/2. Quoting:

- selected_component ::= prefix . selector_name
- selector_name ::= identifier | character_literal | operator_symbol

The prefix (after any implicit dereference) shall resolve to denote an object or value of a specific tagged type T or class-wide type T'Class. The selector_name shall resolve to denote a view of a subprogram declared immediately within the declarative region in which an ancestor of the type T is declared.

Comment: See also [*Rationale for Ada 2005, §2.3 The prefixed notation*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-2-3.html).